# any() all() function in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Write a function isAllLettersUsed(word, required) that takes in a word as the first argument and returns True if the word contains all the letters found in the second argument.

**Examples**

```
>>> isAllLettersUsed('apple', 'apple')
True
>>> isAllLettersUsed('apple', 'google')
False
>>> isAllLettersUsed('learning python', 'google')
True
>>> isAllLettersUsed('learning python', 'apple')
True
```

**What i'm Doing is**

```
def isAllLettersUsed(word, required):
    if all(required in word for required in word):
        return True
    else: 
        return False
```

**And Result returning is**

```
True
True
True
True
```

**Where as it should return as**

```
True
False
True
True
```

i don't understand what should i do at this point i have tried many things but failed. any suggestion??

Comment: `for required in word` means "for each letter in `word`, assign it to a variable named `required` (and incidentally shadow the old one)." You probably want to use `for ch in required` or something similar.

Answer (score 5):

Just see if all letters in required  are in word:

```
def  isAllLettersUsed(word, required):
    return all(ch in word for ch in required)
```

You are checking if the each letter from word is in word by using required in your for loop, required refers to each character not the required parameter passed  so it always returns True as every letter from word has to be in the word.

Comment: No worries, you could use sets which for large strings would be more efficient but I think that is getting away from the main point of your question

Answer (score 1):

```
def isAllLettersUsed(word, required):
    if all(req in word for req in required):
        return True
    else: 
        return False
```

What happened was that you were assigning a value to the variable `required` in your for loop but `required` is a parameter. You want to loop through `required` and save each element of `required` to a new variable. Then, check if that element is in word.

Additionally, your `if-else` is redundant if you use `all()`. Just say `return all(...)`

Answer (score 0):

Change the name of your variables in your generator expression.  You shadowed your argument named `required` with your loop variable `required`.